# Robocopy - include subdirectories of an excluded directory

Tags: robocopy, exclude

I'm using Robocoy to transfer a directory and all it's contents. 
I use the following command as part of a batch file to copy the directories wile ignoring the images subdirectories.

`ROBOCOPY C:\source C:\destination /S /L /XD C:\source\images`

Most of the images in C:\source\images\ are in subdirectories, named entirely through digits (eg `C:\source\images\101\, C:\source\images\102\ .. C:\source\images\2894\`) and I want to continue to exclude all and any of these existing or future numerically named subdirectories.
However, there is also a subdirectory of C:\source\images that I would like to include in the robocopy command; `C:\source\images\static\`.
I had thought I could use wildcards to exclude directories beginning with 1*, 2* .. 9* but this does not work with the exclude directory (/XD) option.

My immediate thought for a workaround (after having written this all out!) is to include a second and subsequent robocopy command

```
ROBOCOPY C:\source C:\destination /S /L /XD C:\source\images
ROBOCOPY C:\source\images\static\ C:\destination\images\static\ /S /L
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect sometimes you just have to break a problem up into parts, or change the way you organise the folders :-)

Also, if you start being too fancy with exclusions or inclusions, you might find you are destroying performance anyway.